# Eigenvalue cleansing methods in R?

Tags: r, covariance-matrix

Are there R packages that offer eigenvalue de-noising methods grounded in Random Matrix Theory? Various cleansing methods include the Power Law and Krazanowski filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tawny](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tawny/tawny.pdf) package in R comes to mind, but are there others? Rmetrics hints at a de-noising procedure using RMT but they do not provide documentation on such a function.

Comment: Are there any other cleansing methods?